# ASP.net controls not obeying CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

Why is is that `Block 1` doesn't render the expected styling and `Block 2` does?

CSS

```
.test
{
    height:3.85in;
    width: 2.625in;
    border: 10px solid  blue;
    padding-right:.25in;
    padding-left:.25in;
    padding-top:.25in;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.test label
{
    font-size:xx-large;
    color:Red;
}
```

Block 1

```
<div  class="test" runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server">Test</asp:Label></div>
```

Block 2

```
<div class="test" runat="server"><label runat="server">text</label></div>
```

The output for the HTML for the two divs is identical.

Comment: Show us the output HTML instead of telling us they're the same.  Let us be the judge of that!

Comment: Ditto that - typically an `<asp:Label />` tag renders to a `<span>` which means your CSS for `.test label` would not work for the `<asp:label />`

Comment: Eli and fnostro are correct,they in fact `DID NOT` render the html the same.

Comment: @fnostro I experimented with different tags and mixed and matched `span` tags and `label` tags.  Good catch.

Comment: isn't working with asp controls fun :)

Comment: @fnostro do you have any clue that the purpose of NOT rendering a label tag is for <asp:Label>?

Comment: Before HTML5 there WAS NO label tag

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - I am not sure why IE chose to always render an <asp:Label> as a SPAN instead of a LABEL, but it is of note to mention the difference between what a LABEL and a SPAN are intended for in the context of a web page.  LABELs are intended to link text to an input element (i.e. input, select, etc.) and in Firefox will be bolded (unless that has changed recently), while a SPAN is just a piece of text that is not necessarily related to any other page element.

Comment: @fnostro The LABEL tag has been around before HTML5, I believe you are thinking of the FORM tag, which is new in HTML5.

Comment: O.o  - come again? Oh - you mean the form attribute - yes

Comment: I just RTFM - seems if you specify the `AssociatedControlId` it renders as an html `<label>` post .NET2 - *oops - nevermind, I'm a day late and a dollar short*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Label server controls render as SPANs in Internet Explorer and not as HTML label elements.  This causes your CSS selector to not be matched for Block 1, but it does match for Block 2.

My recommendation is to add a CSS class name to the ASP.NET Label server control so that it will match the CSS style you want applied to the span/label element.

Comment: "In Internet Explorer" : you mean the output is different for other browsers?

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer renders some tags differently than Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: No, <asp:Label> will render a span tag no matter the browser you are in, check by yourself with the firebug or chromes code inspector...

Comment: <asp:label> only renders a <label> control when the AssociatedControlId is set.

Comment: @Jonathan - You are correct.

Richard Seal - I knew there was a scenario where ASP.NET forced it to be a LABEL, which is the exact reason for when it makes sense to be a LABEL, because it is linked to an INPUT element.

Comment: I have been happily out of the ASP.NET server controls world for a while now, so I have to jog my memory on some of these things.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="test" runat="server">Test</asp:Label>

.test
{
    height:3.85in;
    width: 2.625in;
    border: 10px solid  blue;
    padding-right:.25in;
    padding-left:.25in;
    padding-top:.25in;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:xx-large;
    color:Red;
}
```

Comment: Well he would also need to change the CSS definitions to have the styles specific to the label be applied.  As you wrote this, it would apply the same styles as the DIV had applied to it.